# Adding elements to header Kendo UI Tabstrip

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui, kendo-tabstrip

I use Kendo UI. I create tabstrip. I add in header an element with event handler.
Code:

```
<div>
    <div id="details">
        <div id="tabstrip">
            <ul>
                <li>First tab</li>
                <li>Second tab</li>
            </ul>
            <div id="firstTabPage"></div>
            <div id="secondTabPage"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="indicator" style="float: right">Status</div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#tabstrip").kendoTabStrip();

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#indicator").kendoTooltip({
            content: "<label><input type='checkbox'/>Activate</label><button>Save</button>"
        });
    });
</script>
```

But event is not triggered (Tooltip does not appear). Other events is not triggered also.
What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```
<ul>
    <li>First tab</li>
    <li>Second tab</li>
    <div id="indicator" style="float: right">Status</div>
</ul>
```